Azure Policy to modify Log analytics workspace destination of a data collection rule
I'm trying to write an Azure Policy definition that would modify microsoft.insights/dataCollectionRules/destinations.logAnalytics[*].workspaceResourceId property of a data collection rule to a desired log analytics workspace resource ID.
I found out that I cannot do this using the modify effect type because the property is not a supported alias.
I am trying to achieve this using the deployIfNotExists effect type but having some issues. Below is the policy definition I came up with:
{
    "mode": "Indexed",
    "parameters": {
        "effect": {
            "type": "String",
            "metadata": {
                "displayName": "Effect",
                "description": "The effect determines what happens when the policy rule is evaluated to match"
            },
            "allowedValues": [
                "disabled",
                "Disabled",
                "deployIfNotExists"
            ],
            "defaultValue": "deployIfNotExists"
        },
        "logAnalytics": {
            "type": "String",
            "metadata": {
                "displayName": "Log Analytics workspace",
                "description": "Select Log Analytics workspace from dropdown list. If this workspace is outside of the scope of the assignment you must manually grant 'Log Analytics Contributor' permissions (or similar) to the policy assignment's principal ID.",
                "strongType": "omsWorkspace"
            }
        }
    },
    "policyRule": {
        "if": {
            "field": "type",
            "equals": "Microsoft.Insights/dataCollectionRules"
        },
        "then": {
            "effect": "[parameters('effect')]",
            "details": {
                "type": "microsoft.insights/dataCollectionRules",
                "name": "current",
                "evaluationDelay": "AfterProvisioning",
                "roleDefinitionIds": [
                    "/providers/microsoft.authorization/roleDefinitions/92aaf0da-9dab-42b6-94a3-d43ce8d16293"
                ],
                "existenceCondition": {
                    "field": "microsoft.insights/dataCollectionRules/destinations.logAnalytics[*].workspaceResourceId",
                    "equals": "[parameters('logAnalytics')]"
                },
                "deployment": {
                    "properties": {
                        "mode": "Incremental",
                        "template": {
                            "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
                            "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
                            "parameters": {
                                "logAnalytics": "[parameters('logAnalytics')]"
                            },
                            "resources": [
                                {
                                    "type": "Microsoft.Insights/dataCollectionRules",
                                    "name": "[concat(parameters('resourceName'))]",
                                    "location": "[parameters('location')]",
                                    "properties": {
                                        "destinations": {
                                            "logAnalytics": {
                                                "workspaceResourceId": "[parameters('logAnalytics')]"
                                            }
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            ]
                        },
                        "parameters": {
                            "resourceName": {
                                "value": "[field('name')]"
                            },
                            "logAnalytics": {
                                "value": "[parameters('logAnalytics')]"
                            },
                            "location": {
                                "value": "[field('location')]"
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

However, it does not seem to be working. I am fairly certain that something is wrong with the existenceCondition and also the deployment template itself. could you please point me to the right direction?
